# Simple way to plot a complex valued function of one real variable

Tags: plotting, complex

How can I plot a complex valued function of one real variable, $f(t)$, as

$$x=-\Re f(t),\ z=\Im\ f(t),\ y=t \space?$$

My aim is a 3-dimensional path, treating the complex valued function as if it was a two real components vector valued function.

For example $e^{it}$ can be visualized as a helix in $\mathbb R^3$, in which, for example, the "east-west" axis ($y$) represents the single real variable: $t$, the "north-south" axis ($x$) represents $-\Re f(t)$, and the "top-down" axis ($z$) represents $\Im\ f(t)$.

Comment: how to draw a plot of function like, f(t,y)= yExp(it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plotting the real vs imaginary parts of $e^{ix}$ should be a circle, not a helix. Using ParametricPlot:

```
f[x_] := Exp[I x];
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

In the comments, the OP says that what he really wants is "y should be the real parameter of f, x should be the negative real part, and z should be the imaginary part." One interpretation of this is:

```
f[x_] := Exp[I x];
ParametricPlot3D[{-Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]], x}, {x, 0, 5 Pi}]
```

[image]